# Stopping iAd from loading banners, when I change the view

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, iad

I have an app with UINavigationController. There is ADBannerView on the root view of the navigation controller.

Should I somehow stop recieving ads when I go to another views (and rootView disappears from screen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found some special discussion of this topic on Internet. There is no info about it in iAd Programming Guide. And, according to my own tests (simple breakpoints to delegate methods) - ADBannerView recieves Ads (or process them with delegate methods) only when parent view controller is active.

That's why I suppose the answer to my question is "nothing". I should only correctly place ADBannerView and implement delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the 30 seconds rule, where ad display only count when you show a Ad for more then 30 seconds. This would mean if your user navigate to another view the ad that was displayed on your root doesn't count.

I'm currently trying to figure out how you can display the iAd banner outside the UINavigationController so that the iAd banner remains in view and the change that you hit that 30 seconds increases.